# SPARQL - How to find the data for this site? DSIRE USA

Tags: database, api, sparql, virtuoso

Per the DSIRE USA site (http://www.dsireusa.org/resources/data-and-tools/), they have a Sparql endpoint for the public to use: http://virtuoso.dsireusa.org:8890/sparql. However, I cannot figure out how to find the data via this endpoint. It's got a nice interface to input queries, so I try to follow guides online about how to discover stuff and I'm getting results back but I end up just getting a list of types, and none of those types seem at all related to what I'm looking for.

The website has a limited API interface as well, which has objects called 'programs', 'sectors', 'utilities', etc. and they have their own interface that filters by zip code, city, state, etc. However, they suggest the public user their Sparql endpoint to query this data. The problem is, I can't find anything from this Sparql endpoint that seems to match any of these object names/types.

Can anyone take a look and tell me how I can find a table or set of objects called 'program' or 'programs' from this endpoint?

Comment: "None of those types seem at all related to what I'm looking for..." What are you looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear... The problem is that I don't know for sure what names they've given the types, nor do they have a help site on the subject. All I can do is assume their using the same types as they do with their API, in which case, the type names I'm looking for are 'program', 'sector', 'utility', 'zip code', 'city', 'state', etc.

Comment: Well I played a little and is kind of weird. You can check the classes with "SELECT ?o WHERE{ ?s a ?o }". Also trying I only get things like SQL tablenames and column names.